# How to make Tailwind Cards with same height of the title?

Tags: tailwind-css

So I am using Tailwind 1.9.6 and I want to make 3 cards with same height and titles of same height. I want to use flexbox and not grid because of the browser support.

I have managed to make the cards of same height regardless of the title length, but I would like the clock icon and the published time to also be always on the same height. Right now, the position of the clock icon and date depend on the title length.

How can that be achieved?

Here is the Codepen: https://codepen.io/vladoapost/pen/LYRYgMd

And the code:

```html
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row justify-between mx-4 md:mx-0 lg:-mx-2 flex-wrap">
        <div class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg flex-1 bg-white sm:mx-2 md:mx-1 lg:mx-2 w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:pt-0 border-b-4 border-blue-500 mb-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573748240263-a4e9c57a7fcd" alt="People" class="w-full object-cover h-32 sm:h-48 md:h-64" />
            <div class="p-4 md:p-6 bg-white">
                <p class="text-blue-500 font-semibold text-xs mb-1 leading-none">Teneriffa</p>
                <a href="http://example.test/2020/11/26/hello-world/">
                    <h3 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl leading-tight sm:leading-normal">Hello world!</h3>
                </a>
                <div class="text-sm flex items-center">
                    <svg
                        class="opacity-75 mr-2"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        version="1.1"
                        id="Capa_1"
                        x="0px"
                        y="0px"
                        width="12"
                        height="12"
                        viewBox="0 0 97.16 97.16"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 97.16 97.16;"
                        xml:space="preserve"
                    >
                        <path
                            d="M48.58,0C21.793,0,0,21.793,0,48.58s21.793,48.58,48.58,48.58s48.58-21.793,48.58-48.58S75.367,0,48.58,0z M48.58,86.823    c-21.087,0-38.244-17.155-38.244-38.243S27.493,10.337,48.58,10.337S86.824,27.492,86.824,48.58S69.667,86.823,48.58,86.823z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M73.898,47.08H52.066V20.83c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4c-2.209,0-4,1.791-4,4v30.25c0,2.209,1.791,4,4,4h25.832    c2.209,0,4-1.791,4-4S76.107,47.08,73.898,47.08z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <p class="leading-none">26.11.2020, 10:10 Uhr</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg flex-1 bg-white sm:mx-2 md:mx-1 lg:mx-2 w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:pt-0 border-b-4 border-blue-500 mb-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573748240263-a4e9c57a7fcd" alt="People" class="w-full object-cover h-32 sm:h-48 md:h-64" />
            <div class="p-4 md:p-6 bg-white">
                <p class="text-blue-500 font-semibold text-xs mb-1 leading-none">Gran Canaria</p>
                <a href="http://example.test/2020/11/26/hello-world/">
                    <h3 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl leading-tight sm:leading-normal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
                </a>
                <div class="text-sm flex items-center">
                    <svg
                        class="opacity-75 mr-2"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        version="1.1"
                        id="Capa_1"
                        x="0px"
                        y="0px"
                        width="12"
                        height="12"
                        viewBox="0 0 97.16 97.16"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 97.16 97.16;"
                        xml:space="preserve"
                    >
                        <path
                            d="M48.58,0C21.793,0,0,21.793,0,48.58s21.793,48.58,48.58,48.58s48.58-21.793,48.58-48.58S75.367,0,48.58,0z M48.58,86.823    c-21.087,0-38.244-17.155-38.244-38.243S27.493,10.337,48.58,10.337S86.824,27.492,86.824,48.58S69.667,86.823,48.58,86.823z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M73.898,47.08H52.066V20.83c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4c-2.209,0-4,1.791-4,4v30.25c0,2.209,1.791,4,4,4h25.832    c2.209,0,4-1.791,4-4S76.107,47.08,73.898,47.08z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <p class="leading-none">26.11.2020, 10:10 Uhr</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg flex-1 bg-white sm:mx-2 md:mx-1 lg:mx-2 w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:pt-0 border-b-4 border-blue-500 mb-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573748240263-a4e9c57a7fcd" alt="People" class="w-full object-cover h-32 sm:h-48 md:h-64" />
            <div class="p-4 md:p-6 bg-white">
                <p class="text-blue-500 font-semibold text-xs mb-1 leading-none">Fuerteventura</p>
                <a href="http://example.test/2020/11/26/hello-world/">
                    <h3 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl leading-tight sm:leading-normal">Hello world!</h3>
                </a>
                <div class="text-sm flex items-center">
                    <svg
                        class="opacity-75 mr-2"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        version="1.1"
                        id="Capa_1"
                        x="0px"
                        y="0px"
                        width="12"
                        height="12"
                        viewBox="0 0 97.16 97.16"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 97.16 97.16;"
                        xml:space="preserve"
                    >
                        <path
                            d="M48.58,0C21.793,0,0,21.793,0,48.58s21.793,48.58,48.58,48.58s48.58-21.793,48.58-48.58S75.367,0,48.58,0z M48.58,86.823    c-21.087,0-38.244-17.155-38.244-38.243S27.493,10.337,48.58,10.337S86.824,27.492,86.824,48.58S69.667,86.823,48.58,86.823z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M73.898,47.08H52.066V20.83c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4c-2.209,0-4,1.791-4,4v30.25c0,2.209,1.791,4,4,4h25.832    c2.209,0,4-1.791,4-4S76.107,47.08,73.898,47.08z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <p class="leading-none">26.11.2020, 10:10 Uhr</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution by adding `flex flex-col` directives to some of your containers (the one containing your image and the card body, and to the card body itself) and `flex-1` to the card body (to make it take the entire left space) and to the `a` wrapping your `h3`.

I don't know if the written explanation is that clear but check the snippet, it should do a better job!

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container mx-auto">
  <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row justify-between mx-4 md:mx-0 lg:-mx-2 flex-wrap">
    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg flex-1 bg-white sm:mx-2 md:mx-1 lg:mx-2 w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:pt-0 border-b-4 border-blue-500 mb-10 flex flex-col">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573748240263-a4e9c57a7fcd" alt="People" class="w-full object-cover h-32 sm:h-48 md:h-64" />
      <div class="p-4 md:p-6 bg-white flex flex-col flex-1">
        <p class="text-blue-500 font-semibold text-xs mb-1 leading-none">Teneriffa</p>
        <a href="http://example.test/2020/11/26/hello-world/" class="flex-1">
          <h3 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl leading-tight sm:leading-normal">Hello world!</h3>
        </a>
        <div class="text-sm flex items-center">
          <svg class="opacity-75 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 97.16 97.16" style="enable-background: new 0 0 97.16 97.16;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path
                            d="M48.58,0C21.793,0,0,21.793,0,48.58s21.793,48.58,48.58,48.58s48.58-21.793,48.58-48.58S75.367,0,48.58,0z M48.58,86.823    c-21.087,0-38.244-17.155-38.244-38.243S27.493,10.337,48.58,10.337S86.824,27.492,86.824,48.58S69.667,86.823,48.58,86.823z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M73.898,47.08H52.066V20.83c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4c-2.209,0-4,1.791-4,4v30.25c0,2.209,1.791,4,4,4h25.832    c2.209,0,4-1.791,4-4S76.107,47.08,73.898,47.08z"></path>
                    </svg>
          <p class="leading-none">26.11.2020, 10:10 Uhr</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg flex-1 bg-white sm:mx-2 md:mx-1 lg:mx-2 w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:pt-0 border-b-4 border-blue-500 mb-10 flex flex-col">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573748240263-a4e9c57a7fcd" alt="People" class="w-full object-cover h-32 sm:h-48 md:h-64" />
      <div class="p-4 md:p-6 bg-white flex flex-col flex-1">
        <p class="text-blue-500 font-semibold text-xs mb-1 leading-none">Gran Canaria</p>
        <a href="http://example.test/2020/11/26/hello-world/" class="flex-1">
          <h3 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl leading-tight sm:leading-normal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
        </a>
        <div class="text-sm flex items-center">
          <svg class="opacity-75 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 97.16 97.16" style="enable-background: new 0 0 97.16 97.16;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path
                            d="M48.58,0C21.793,0,0,21.793,0,48.58s21.793,48.58,48.58,48.58s48.58-21.793,48.58-48.58S75.367,0,48.58,0z M48.58,86.823    c-21.087,0-38.244-17.155-38.244-38.243S27.493,10.337,48.58,10.337S86.824,27.492,86.824,48.58S69.667,86.823,48.58,86.823z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M73.898,47.08H52.066V20.83c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4c-2.209,0-4,1.791-4,4v30.25c0,2.209,1.791,4,4,4h25.832    c2.209,0,4-1.791,4-4S76.107,47.08,73.898,47.08z"></path>
                    </svg>
          <p class="leading-none">26.11.2020, 10:10 Uhr</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg flex-1 bg-white sm:mx-2 md:mx-1 lg:mx-2 w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:pt-0 border-b-4 border-blue-500 mb-10 flex flex-col">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573748240263-a4e9c57a7fcd" alt="People" class="w-full object-cover h-32 sm:h-48 md:h-64" />
      <div class="p-4 md:p-6 bg-white flex flex-col flex-1">
        <p class="text-blue-500 font-semibold text-xs mb-1 leading-none">Fuerteventura</p>
        <a href="http://example.test/2020/11/26/hello-world/" class="flex-1">
          <h3 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl leading-tight sm:leading-normal">Hello world!</h3>
        </a>
        <div class="text-sm flex items-center">
          <svg class="opacity-75 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 97.16 97.16" style="enable-background: new 0 0 97.16 97.16;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path
                            d="M48.58,0C21.793,0,0,21.793,0,48.58s21.793,48.58,48.58,48.58s48.58-21.793,48.58-48.58S75.367,0,48.58,0z M48.58,86.823    c-21.087,0-38.244-17.155-38.244-38.243S27.493,10.337,48.58,10.337S86.824,27.492,86.824,48.58S69.667,86.823,48.58,86.823z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M73.898,47.08H52.066V20.83c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4c-2.209,0-4,1.791-4,4v30.25c0,2.209,1.791,4,4,4h25.832    c2.209,0,4-1.791,4-4S76.107,47.08,73.898,47.08z"></path>
                    </svg>
          <p class="leading-none">26.11.2020, 10:10 Uhr</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @edemots, I have a different card an your img solution works for me too